# MongoDB default filter

Tags: java, mongodb

I have below mongo collection structure

```
{ 
  "status": "active", 
  "country": "GB"
}
```

and wanted to apply filter for `country` field for all the queries to this collection. Kindly help.

NOTE: We are not using spring-mongo to use the interceptor. It would be helpful if there is any method using mongo java driver

Comment: I don't think there is a `default filter` concept. You need to handle it in your query.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a default filter you can add to all queries. What you can do however is create a [view](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createView/) which will drop the unwanted fields like so:

```
db.createView("new_view", "collection", [{$project: {country: 0}}])
```

Now the `new_view` will behave like a collection that you can query, mind you views are read only. hence any update that you'll require will have to be performed on the original `collection`.